# AndroidStudio 3.1.2 suddenly displays imports as not resolved

Tags: android-studio, gradle

Just over night AndroidStudio 3.1.2 is not able to resolve some imports. Pretty much only those downloaded remotely. On all my projects.

I have cleaned the project(s) multiple times. 
I have Invalidated Caches and restarted AndroidStudio multiple times. 
I have manually deleted all the cache from ~/.gradle/caches

AndroidStudio can still not resolve those libraries.

The weirdest thing is that the libraries seems to be downloaded because I can successfully build and launch the apps in my projects. As can be seen in the screenshot below the build is successful and running the app works.

Shouldn't it complain when I build the project that some dependencies can't be resolved?

[image]

My project level build.gradle looks like this:

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.2.41'
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
        google()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.2'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.0'
        classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.8'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-android-extensions:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
```

Whats going on here?

Comment: If it looks like your `not able to resolve some imports` but they really **are** resolved because you can build and run, then **only** the *markup* part of `Android Studio` is some how damaged/not working/out of date/conflicted/has a bug. Check your plugins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end I totally uninstalled Android Studio and clean installed it again to get it working.